Is 120 kW DC Tesla charger dangerous to humans to come in contact with?
I know what high voltage AC currently to does to the body and heart in term of ventral fibrillation but what are the dangers posed by a Tesla DC charger electrical contacts. Although the probability of a person coming into contact with it is low due to safety features including insulation and charging protocol, what would happen if you come into live contact with the electrical conductors of a 120kW Tesla charger when energized?

"what would happen if you come into live contact with the electrical conductors of a 120kW Tesla charger when energized?"  Likely you would then be given a nice funeral.

Keep in mind that (AFAIK) all car charging stations are designed not to present dangerous voltage on the connector until it is established that the connector is fully seated in the car's port. This means that you need to work very hard to electrocute yourself.

A 120 kW Tesla charger uses 500 VDC. Although DC is less dangerous than AC, 500 VDC is more than enough to kill you.
There is a lot of information out there, search for "electrocution by dc vs ac".
